# Polynomial invariant relating the circumradius and sides of a cyclic polygon

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, invariant-theory, symmetric-functions, multilinear-algebra

This question deals with the polynomial invariant which relates the circumradius and the squares of the sides of a cyclic polygon.

This invariant is discussed briefly in the seminal paper [On the Areas of Cyclic and Semicyclic Polygons](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407300) (see section 5, equation (10)); a more in-depth discussion is had in a paper by Igor Pak [Rigidity and polynomial invariants of convex polytopes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/papers/pp16.pdf) (see sections 7.6 and 9); an elimination theory approach is discussed in a paper by Varfolomeev [Inscribed polygons and Heron polynomials](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM2003v194n03ABEH000718) (the paper is not free to access). There are some more papers from the 2000's which deal with this problem, but the above papers seem to be the most encompassing.

I came across this problem when studying certain transformations of Chebyshev polynomials. I would like to go beyond the aforementioned papers, as in to give the "most explicit" formula for the aforementioned polynomial invariant **in the general case**, but this seems to be quite difficult.

I am asking if there have been any advances on finding a "most explicit" formula **in the general case** since 2004, and for other useful ideas.

### **Edit

By "general case" I mean the case where the number of sides of the polygon is arbitrary.

By "most explicit formula" I mean **the** monomial expansion.

Comment: Could you clarify: What is "the general case"?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke When the number of sides of the polygon is arbitrary. There is the paper [On Circumradius Equations of Cyclic Polygons](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/402976.main1.pdf)  where small cases are computed, but the formula for the general case leaves something to be desired in terms of "explicitness"